# Is there a way to fire ResourceTaskStart block programmatically without a Downtime block?

Tags: function, anylogic

Leading into a preparedUnits port of a Seize block, I'd like a cart to arrive at a dropoff location before the delivery truck arrives at the same spot. I thought there would be a function similar to a `source.inject(1);` for this block, but I'm not finding anything quite like that. Does something similar exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how the block is supposed to work.

If you want to design an upfront flow manually, you need to manage it yourself:
You either put an "Enter" block and use `enter.take(myAgent)` to start a custom flow. Or you use a source block to create a new agent for your custom flow.